# Job scheduling simulation C++. Code structure suggestions and adding the aspect of Time

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct, simulation

I am trying to create a code in c++ to simulate job scheduling with algorithms. Lets say its with FiFo cause its a simple one.
I have a  FiFo.cpp that wil deal with the array of the jobs , and i have written a poisson.cpp to generate numbers from poisson distribution for my job arrivals.
My main problem is how to input the aspect of time and **how to connect these together** with my other .cpp (structurewise). For example how to add the prospect of "  #ticks have passed a job will arrive. "

I tried using ctime library with variables like this clock_t T1=clock() but i havent been able to measure something good(they appear to be ints).

P.s My problems are not so well described cause i am pretty confused now :P

Comment: C++11 has built-in support for Poisson distributions, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/poisson_distribution

Comment: Also with C++11, you can measure time with higher resolution than seconds, see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono.

Comment: thanks i will have a look at those two

Comment: If you are simulating, why do you have to wait real time seconds?

Comment: i though i did until now. do you have anything good to read about it?

Comment: Dimitris, please check out the link I've provided in a response to your related question. There are many textbooks and papers that can tell you how to do discrete-event simulation, which is the modeling paradigm I'd recommend for your problem.